# Joomla Article Function

Tags: joomla

I am learning Joomla,but I am confused about some function.if you want to show “Title” in wordpress, you have to write “the_title();”,or if you want to show “Content” you have to write “the_content” or you want to show “image” you  have to write “the_post_thumbnail” .but if you want to show same thing in Joomla,what function can I use here?.Please help me, I have no knowledge about PHP.

Answer (score 1):

With Joomla you are not supposed to write PHP to generate content. Joomla supplies "articles", "categories" and a lot of other types of objects for content.

You create an article and just write your content in it. Titles are created automatically from the name of your article.

Joomla also has separated layout from content, much like Wordpress. On Joomla the equivalent of "widgets" are modules, of which there are many already builtin and thousands more to extend with.

Considering that Wordpress have the same basic functionality, perhaps you are trying to "program" a Joomla template? If so, Joomla Docs have much information for you, perhaps [this page](https://docs.joomla.org/Creating_a_basic_Joomla!_template) can be a starting point to the Joomla template API.

I suggest you google for "joomla introduction" and watch some of the video intros there.

There is also the special [Joomla Stackexchange](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/) where you can ask more Joomla related questions and get better answers.

Comment: If the answer helped you, and think it can help others with the same question, you can accept it by clicking the checkmark beside the answer. Thanks!